# dbc.Select() setting dropdown to required doesn't automatically outline an empty dropdown in DASH

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm creating a plotly-Dash form and using bootstraps `dbc.Select()` to create a dropdown.  I want it to be outlined with a red border as I have with my `dbc.Input()` boxes when nothing is selected, but it doesn't appear to be working.  What am I doing wrong?  I set `required = True` as I did with my `dbc.Input()` but no outline:

```
dbc.Select(
    id="temperature",
    required=True,
    options=[{'label': 'Heated', 'value': 'Heated'},
             {'label': 'Ambient', 'value': 'Ambient'},
             {'label': 'N/A', 'value': 'N/A'}],
             value=temperature[0]
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the required field is not working for `dbc.Select`, but there is a workaround to getting required working for it.

You could have a callback triggered either by selecting a value for the dropdown or using `dcc.Interval` and checking if `dropdown.value is None`. You could also add an empty option into the dropdown and extend the check to `dropdown.value is None or dropdown.value == ""` in case the user selects it. if the condition is true, then set the required attribute to true and have some css style for :required pseudo class to some color (e.g. `#SOME_INPUT:required {border: 1px solid red;})`.

Something like the following could be used as a template:

```py
select = dbc.Select(
    id="dropdown-required",
    required=True,
    options=[
            {'label': '', 'value': ''},
            {'label': 'Heated', 'value': 'Heated'},
            {'label': 'Ambient', 'value': 'Ambient'},
            {'label': 'N/A', 'value': 'N/A'}],
)
app.layout = html.Div([select])

@app.callback(
    Output("dropdown-required", "required"),
    Input("dropdown-required", "value")
)
def set_dropdown_required(value):
    res = (
        True if value is None or value == "" 
        else False
    ) 
    return res
```

and some css styling under `assets/style.css`:

```
#dropdown-required:required {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```